# $ionicPop.show() Fails

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Ok so I've done this a hundred times in other projects but for some reason I keep getting an error on `$ionicPopup.show({})`

I have an ng-click in the HTML that calls loginPressed()

This is the error I get: `TypeError: $ionicPopup.show is not a function`

Here's the code for the controller and the version of Ionic is 1.3.2:

```
.controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$ionicPopup', 
'$rootScope', '$state',
function ($scope, $ionicPopup, $stateParams, $state) {
  $scope.$on("$ionicView.loaded", function (event, data) {
    console.log("called ionicView loaded");
    $scope.data = {};
    var num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);
    $scope.data.bgImage = "url(img/bg" + "-" + num + ".jpg)";
  });
  $scope.loginPressed = function () {
    console.log($ionicPopup);
      var loginPopUp = $ionicPopup.show({
      template: '<input type="email" ng-model="data.email"> <input type="password" ng-model="data.model"> ',
      title: 'Login',
      scope: $scope,
      buttons: [
        {text: 'Cancel'},
        {
          text: '<b>Login</b>',
          type: 'button-dark',
          onTap: function (e) {
            if (!$scope.data.email || !$scope.data.password) {
              e.preventDefault();
            } else {
              return $scope;
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    loginPopUp.then(function (res) {
      console.log('Tapped!', res);
    })
  };
}])
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The controller function parameters don't match the order of the strings in the array.

Change to:

```
['$scope', '$stateParams', '$ionicPopup', '$rootScope', '$state',
function ($scope, $stateParams, $ionicPopup, $rootScope, $state) {
```

Comment: I feel like such dolt! I forgot that order matters. Thank you so much!